# NuGet deleted my entire project

Tags: .net, visual-studio-2012, nuget, xsockets.net

I was using NuGet to install XSockets custom configuration into my project, and then *kaboom*, my entire project disappeared along with all the files. I followed part 12 in their [video tutorials](http://xsockets.net/video-tutorials), so you can see the exact same thing of what I did (basically `PM> Scaffold XSockets.Configuration`).

What it should've done is add a file to my project, but instead all my files disappeared! My question is: how do I recover files that NuGet somehow mysteriously deleted? Was there any newbie mistake that I did? (this is my first time using NuGet's Package Manager Console)

Many thanks... this is highly worrying, I just lost my entire ASP.NET project.

Comment: Are you positive they were 100% deleted from the physical drive? Not just removed from the project?

Comment: When I looked at the folder in Windows Explorer, it was gone. And then in Visual Studio all the items were marked as missing, and the project couldn't be loaded when I restarted VS. So, yep, definitely.

Comment: Ah, good thing you had that all under source control.

Comment: Hello Matt. That sounds really nasty! I am one of the developers behind XSockets.NET and I can asure you that there is nothing in the scaffolder that would do something like that. Never heard of such a thing happening. Hope that you can get back on track a.s.a.p

Answer (score 1):

If you are using Windows 7 or Windows 8, you can try the "[previous version of files](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows7/previous-versions-of-files-frequently-asked-questions)" feature.

**Edit**

Glad you recover your project. Sorry it is three day old. There is no obvious reason why your project files have been erased. Did something strange happened during the operation (slugginess, strange hard drive noises)? Have you tried a disk analysis for bad sectors? Have you analyzed your disk for viruses and malware? Could your project files be located in a place where some automatic cleanup occurs? Please also have a glance in the event logs: it could help to check if some disk errors or other things happened during the operation.

I remember having some source files corrupted because of a network error occured during a save operation (I worked on a shared disk). It was marked in the system event log, so could prove it and saved my ass.

Comment: This helped to get a project dated 3 days back, thank you very much. But I'm wondering why my end result is different from the vid demo even though I did the same thing...

Answer (score 0):

Ouch. Nuget doesn't keep a copy of the project and has a direct file access to the system. So nuget won't be the savior in this case.  I hope you have version control? If not, start this would be a very good time to start. There are a bunch of solutions that don't require a server and can run completely locally.

Other options. You can stop using the hard drive ASAP so you can use unerase methods. As Laurent said previous versions is available on certain OSes. Lastly, if you still have the compiled assemblies you could use a decompiler like [dotpeek](http://www.jetbrains.com/decompiler/) to get the source code back but you'd still have to recover the static assets like JavaScript and images.